# Solving $T(n) = 16T(n/2) + n$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem

I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation :-

$T(n)=16T(n/2)+n$ using masters theorem. I got $\Theta (n^2)$ (Which matched the first case in the theory) which is wrong, any help with this please?

Comment: How did you get $\Theta(n^2)$? Show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's review the master theorem:

> The following theorem can be used to determine the running time of divide and conquer algorithms. For a given program (algorithm), first we try to find the recurrence relation for the problem. If the recurrence is of the below form then we can directly given the answer without fully solving it. If the recurrence is of the form $T(n) = aT(\frac{n}{b}) + \Theta(n^k\log^p n)$, where $a \geq 1$, $b > 1$, $k \geq 0$, and $p$ is a real number, then:
>
> 1. If $a > b^k$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$.
> 2. If $a = b^k$:
>
>    - a. If $p > -1$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log^{p+1} n)$.
>    - b. If $p = -1$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log\log n)$.
>    - c. If $p < -1$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$.
> 3. If $a < b^k$:
>
>    - a. If $p \geq 0$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^k \log^p n)$.
>    - b. If $p < 0$, then $T(n) = O(n^k)$.

Source :
Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy : Data Structure and Algorithmic Puzzles

In your example, we have

1. $a = 16$
2. $b = 2$
3. $k = 1$
4. $p = 0$

Then, $a = 16$ and $b^k = 2^1 = 2$.

So we have $a > b^k$, which is case 1.

So our answer is $\Theta(n^{\log_b a}) = \Theta(n^{\log_216}) = \Theta(n^4)$.

Comment: You can use markdown and MathJax here. Also, it's better to use text rather than images, to accommodate screen readers. Finally, you should acknowledge the source of your image that I transcribed for you.